# Помогите исправить ошибки в программе

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Помогите исправить такие ошибки в программе:

> '=': function as left operand
>   cannot determine which instance of overloaded function "cos" is intended

Код программы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.14159265 

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
        double * x = new double(0.5);
        double **px = &x;

    cos = (pow(**px, 3) -  pow(**px, 2));
    cout << "cos=pow(**px, 3) - pow(**px, 2)" << endl;
    cout << "cos= " << **px;
    cout.precision(4);
    delete *px;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Само задание такое:
Используя вместо самой переменной указатель на нее, написать программу в соответствии с заданием:
Вычислить y = cos|x3-x2|.

Comment: А где ошибки-то, Катя?

Comment: @Катя  А что означает переменная cos? Ошибка заключается в том, что компилятор рассматривает это имя как имя стандартной функции.

Comment: нужен ли здесь тэг [tag:visual-studio] ? про саму IDE не слова, но может специалисту сразу ясно особенности компилятора? но тогда, наверное и версию надо указывать?

Comment: @4per: Не, не Visual Studio, иначе было бы `#include "stdafx.h"`.

Comment: @VladD, не совсем понятно - почему "иначе было бы" ?

Comment: @VladD много лет пишу в студии и нигде нет stdafx и не будет. Так что нельзя исключать студию...

Comment: Ну, создайте консольный проект в студии с настройками по умолчанию, там будет `#include "stdafx.h"` в .cpp-файле.

Comment: @VladD, да, Ваша правда. Но Вы сами указали на условия, при которых появляется этот ```stdafx.h```. Я как-то всегда пустой проект создаю, и уже даже забыл, как этот файл выглядит )

Comment: @VladD по умолчанию - будет. Но stdafx не обязателен и, в общем, не нужен.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: Не обязателен — да. Насчёт «не нужен» я бы поспорил: в больших проектах скорость компиляции критична.

Comment: @VladD, только в больших проектах наверняка свои precompiled-headers.

Answer (score 2):

Вот это - `double * x = new double(0.5)` - лишнее, Вы ведь не под массив память выделяете. Метод `precision` нужно выполнить до того, как Вы что-то отправите в std::cout, иначе какой от него прок.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.14159265 

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    double x = 0.5;
    double* px = &x;

    double res = pow( *px, 3 ) -  pow( *px, 2 );
    cout << "cos=pow(*px, 3) - pow(*px, 2)" << endl;
    cout.precision(4);
    cout << "f(x) = cos(0.5) = " << res;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

в строке

```
cos = (pow(**px, 3) -  pow(**px, 2));
```

ошибка.
нужно

```
double res = cos(abs(pow(*px,3)-pow(*px,2)));
```

и в начале просто объявить

```
double *px = new double(0.5);
```

и еще в cpp нужно писать

```
#include <cmath>
```

Comment: Можете объяснить, зачем нужно использовать ```double *px = new double(0.5);``` данную конструкцию ?

Comment: ну  нужно указатель использовать? саму переменную можно вообще не объявлять, а просто указатель инициализировать сразу.

Comment: _вместо самой переменной указатель на нее_ - как-бы переменная то быть должна. Как я понимаю, это какое-то очень простое задание, которое знакомит _Катю_ с указателями )) Вообще, это не важно, просто такие конструкции - очень странные.

Comment: ну в java объекты же так создаются, а там объекты это по сути указатели.